# How could assigning text to a string be an invalid cast?

Tags: c#, string, ms-access, ms-access-2007, .net

I'm getting "InvalidCastException" although the data in question is a string, and all the code refers to it as such.

Here's the Model:

```
public class Vendor
{
    [Required]
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the query:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT contact_id as VendorID, company_name FROM t_contacts where type = 'V'";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbDataReader oleDbD8aReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oleDbD8aReader != null && oleDbD8aReader.Read())
        {
            var vendorId = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(0);
            var companyName = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(1);
            Add(new Vendor { VendorId = vendorId, CompanyName = companyName });
        }
    }
}
```

The two columns being queried in the MS Access table  are strings (Text Fieldsize 10 for contact_id, Text Fieldsize 50 for company_name). "Type" is text Fieldsize 1.

The err msg indicates it thinks company_name is an int:

*System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.ValueString()
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
       at HandheldServer.Models.VendorRepository..ctor() in c:\HandheldServer\HandheldServer\Models\VendorRepository.cs:line 35*

Line 35 is:

```
string companyName = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(1);
```

How could assigning the contents of company_name (Text 50) to a string result in an invalid cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked to see what the database driver is returning?

I'm willing to bet that it's returning a SQL `null`, which is manifestly neither a C# `null` nor a string. The exception is being thrown from inside the `GetString()` method if you look at the stack trace.

Before invoking `GetString()` you have to verify that the column is the desired type (a string) and that it is non-null. The `OleDbDataReader.IsDBNull()` method indicates nullity.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the assigning of a string object to a string variable that's the issue, because that would have been picked up at compile time.  The issue is that that GetString method must internally cast the Object reference stored in the data reader as type String and that is failing at run time, so the data reader does not contain a String in that column.  If the column data type is textual then the only possible reason for the issue is that the column contains NULL.  The data reader has its own IsDbNull method to test for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it; you can choose which is the kludgier:

Way A:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT contact_id as VendorID, company_name FROM t_contacts where type = 'V'";

while (oleDbD8aReader != null && oleDbD8aReader.Read())
{
    if (!oleDbD8aReader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        vendorId = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(0);
    }
    else
    {
        vendorId = "blank";
    }
    if (!oleDbD8aReader.IsDBNull(1))
    {
        companyName = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(1);
    }
    else
    {
        companyName = "blank";
    }
    Add(new Vendor { VendorId = vendorId, CompanyName = companyName });
}
```

Way Bee:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IIF(ISNULL(contact_id),'[blank]', contact_id), IIF(ISNULL(company_name),'[blank]', company_name) FROM t_contacts where type = 'V'";

while (oleDbD8aReader != null && oleDbD8aReader.Read())
{
    vendorId = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(0);
    companyName = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(1);
    Add(new Vendor { VendorId = vendorId, CompanyName = companyName });
}
```